# Android JSONObject parsing issue

Tags: android, json

Was trying to use the android JSON object to parse a particular response, but am unable to make a code that would parse this response "{"r":{"f":[1,0,15,5948]}}".

Tried using below code, but am getting error :

**"No value for f : {"r":{"f":[1,0,15,5948]}}"**

Code is as follows:

```
String abc = "{\"r\":{\"f\":[1,0,15,5948]}}";

JSONObject json = new JSONObject(abc);

if (json.has("r")) {

Bundle b = new Bundle();

b.putInt("p", json.getJSONArray("f").getInt(0));

b.putInt("s", json.getJSONArray("f").getInt(1));

}
```

I intend to parse the above response and get the values in bundle respective variables.
Like `b.putInt("p", json.getJSONArray("f").getInt(0));` should get the 1 in f:[1....]
and so forth.

Can somebody help in having a working code for getting the values for above reponse.

Answer (score 2):

`"f"` is a sub element of `"r"`, therefore you need to access it like this:

`getJSONObject("r").getJSONArray("f")`

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

`b.putInt("p", json.getJSONArray("f").getInt(0));`

the `json` variable still references root object of your json. You have to traverse down one level to access field f.

This works for me:

```
String abc = "{\"r\":{\"f\":[1,0,15,5948]}}";
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(abc);
if (json.has("r")) {
    json = json.getJSONObject("r");
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt("p", json.getJSONArray("f").getInt(0));
    b.putInt("s", json.getJSONArray("f").getInt(1));
}
```

Note line:

**json = json.getJSONObject("r");**

Comment: Thank you smuk, i would check if that help me get the values.